# How to change the projection and resolution of a file using gdal?

Tags: gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I have a file with these information:

```py
lat_min -60.0
lat_max 80.0
lon_min -180.0
lon_max 179.9
lon_sampling 0.1 degree
lat_sampling 0.1 degree
samples = 3600
lines   = 1401
```

I want to re-project the file to

I tried

```py
 gdalwarp -of "ENVI" -t_srs `EPSG:3410`  -ts 1383 586 but give error
 gdalwarp -of "ENVI" -t_srs "+proj=cea +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=30 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371228 +b=6371228 +units=m +no_defs" -ts 1383 586 -ot Float32  file.envi file_1383586.envi 
ERROR 1: No PROJ.4 translation for source SRS, coordinate transformation initialization has failed
```

Comment: If you want to resample your image to a given number of pixels you are looking for the `-ts` option instead of `-tr` which refers to the size of a individual pixel. Your command should look like: `gdalwarp -of "ENVI" -t_srs `EPSG:3410` -ts 1383 586 input.envi output.envi` Depending on your data I suggest also taking a look at the [possible resampling algorithms](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) which can be invoked with `-r`

Comment: Please provide more info on your error than 'but give wrong file'. What is wrong? Resolution, size, is there an Error message?

Comment: @hyat you need to convert the input file into something that GDAL can understand. As is, that is where GDAL throws the error.

Comment: The copy.com link shows me "Sorry, you must be signed in to view this privately shared content."

Comment: GDAL could not find automatically the source srs, therefore it can't know how to do the conversion into your -t_srs. You must give also a correct -s_srs.

Comment: CRS is not defined, you should first do : gdal_edit.py -a_srs EPSG:4326 yourfilepath (assuming here that it should be WGS84, to be checked)

Comment: But the metadata in .hdr is rubbish with origin at 0,1 and very little pixel size even if considered to be in degrees `map info = {Arbitrary, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0.000277777777777778, 0.000713775874375446, 0, North}` If you know who made the image I suggest to contact them and ask them to make a proper header file.

Answer (score 3):

Since the files metadata is incomplete, you have to add it manually:

```
gdal_translate -a_srs epsg:4326 -a_ullr -180 80 179.9 -60 file.envi test.tif
```

and the result fits nicely to Natural Earth coastline, ready for further warping:

```
gdalwarp -of "ENVI" -t_srs "+proj=cea +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=30 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371228 +b=6371228 +units=m +no_defs" -ts 1383 586 -ot Float32  test.tif file_1383586.envi
```

[image]

Comment: -a:srs? you mean -a_srs. I had an error `ERROR 4: `.envi' not recognised as a supported file format.`

Comment: I loaded the tif into QGIS, and the Natural Earth shape as well. You are right, -a:srs was a typo. Did you get the `Error 4` with gdal_translate or with gdalwarp? I had no problem with the latest GDAL from gisinternals.

Comment: gdal_translate  may be I have to install the same version of gdal you used.What you think?

Comment: Surely. Format drivers may have been improved. GDAL 1.11.2 is the latest stable. On Linux and MacOS, available drivers may be different.